# Is it possible to use or import Processing classes in android?

Tags: java, android, processing

i have multiple question ..

We can run processing sketches on Android as well as IPhone

I mean is it possible to upload code written in [Processing](https://www.processing.org/examples/) to Play Store. if yes guide me .if it is not possible . Give me guide line . I will try to right it for android . help me out.

if it is not possible . Tell me the difference between processing and android . both are in java. 
See example [here](https://www.processing.org/examples/easing.html)..

Comment: android is not programming language android sdk provides APIs written in java to develop applications for android. most (not all) android application client sides are developed in pure java and xml only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked whether it's possible to upload a Processing Android project to Google Play, and the answer is yes. Just generate the APK, sign it, and go through the process outlined on the Google Play upload page.

You asked what the difference between Processing and Android is. That's not really a valid question, as Android is an entire ecosystem and Processing is a language and library.

Comment: can you guide me or give me some tutorial which tell me how to launch processing In Eclipse or what is the procedure of creating a Signed Apk from Processing..

Comment: [This](http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/) is the first result for googling "Processing eclipse". [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) is the first result for googling "signing apk".